# how to convert timestamp string to java.util.Date

Tags: java

I need to convert a timestamp string to `java.util.Date`. E.g.:

`MMDDYYHHMMSS` to `MM-DD-YY HH-MM-SS`

Where `MM` is month, `DD` is date, `YY` is year, `HH` is hours, `MM` is minutes and `SS` is seconds.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You *can* do it like this:

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMddyyHHmmss");
Date date = format.parse("022310141505");
```

but I would *strongly* recommend that you use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) instead. It's a better date/time library by a long, long way. In particular, the formatters/parsers in Joda Time are thread-safe, so you can reuse them freely and statically; `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` *isn't* thread-safe, so you either need to create one per thread or serialize access to it with a `synchronized` block.

Comment: gentle request.could you pls post one example.

Comment: Another victim of the upper/lowercase gotcha - "S" is milliseconds.

Comment: how to convert the above using JSTL tags

Comment: @Manu: I would suggest not doing it in a template tag to start with, to be honest.

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

```
java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(
    "012318123456" ,
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MMdduuHHmmss" )
).format( 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MM-dd-uu HH-mm-ss" )
)
```

> 01-23-18 12-34-56

## java.time

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes.

Define a formatting pattern to match your input string.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MMdduuHHmmss" ) ;
```

Your two-digit year will be interpreted as being 21st century ( 20xx ).

Parse as a `LocalDateTime` because your input string lacks any indicator of time zone or offset-from-UTC.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( "012318123456" , f ) ;
```

> ldt.toString(): 2018-01-23T12:34:56

Generate a string in your desired format.

```
DateTimeFormatter fOut = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MM-dd-uu HH-mm-ss" ) ;
String output = ldt.format( fOut  );
```

> 01-23-18 12-34-56

## ISO 8601

Both of your formats are terrible, for multiple reasons.

When serializing date-time values, use the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats whenever possible. They are designed to be practical, easy to parse by machine, easy to read by humans across cultures.

For a date-time time such as yours, the `T` in the middle separates the date portion from the time-of-day portion.

> 2018-01-23T12:34:56

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

use a [SimpleDateFormat](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) with an appropriate format string (be careful to use the correct format letters, uppercase and lowercase have different meanings!).

Comment: gentle request.could you pls post one example.

Comment: how to convert the above using JSTL tags