# converting timestamp to date in java

Tags: java, mysql, web-services, soap, valueconverter

This is my database:
[image]

Here I have to check the query current date+status=Q information and get the count value.

This is my code:

```
public class TodayQ {
    public int data() {
         int count=0;
        Date date = new Date(timestamp);
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy-MM-dd");
System.out.println( dateFormat.format (date));

        // count++;

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pro", "root", "");

            PreparedStatement statement = con
                    .prepareStatement("select * from orders where status='Q' AND date=CURDATE()");
            ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
            while (result.next()) {
                // Do something with the row returned.
                count++; // if the first col is a count.
            }

        }

        catch (Exception exc) {
            System.out.println(exc.getMessage());
        }

        return count;
    }

}
```

Here I have to edit the date is (yyyy-mm-dd) format. Now I got the output. But I wish to use timestamp on my database. So how is converted timestamp to date in Java. How is use that code in my code?

Comment: there is TimeStamp class in Java may be sql.timestamp .. check it out this might help you.

Comment: Check this link for converting Timestamp to date. 

[TimeStamp to Date][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318719/how-to-convert-timestamp-string-to-java-util-date

Comment: What SQL type is the date column?

Comment: That's not an answer. What SQL type is the *date column?*

Comment: @krishnaveni what kind of example do you want?

Comment: **Do not re-post your Question repeatedly!** This was [re-posted days later](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11839246/642706). There I posted [a lengthy Answer using modern *java.time* classes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48614601/642706).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve the same using mysql functions. Hope the following query gives you the desired output.

```
select * 
from orders
where status='Q' AND 
      date_format(from_unixtime(date),'%Y-%m-%d') = current_date;
```

Comment: Hi how is get the count value for this month.i have to use below query.select * from orders where status='Q' AND DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(date),'%Y-%m-%d')=MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURDATE()) AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURDATE()).but is not gave me the correct count value.displayed 0 only.

Comment: this query works for you. select count(1) from orders where status='Q' AND DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(ts),'%Y-%m')= DATE_FORMAT(now(), '%Y-%m')

Answer (score 2):

```
Date date = new Date(timestamp);
```

whereas timestamp is a long variable

Comment: i got dis exception error:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
 at java.util.Date.parse(Date.java:598)
 at java.util.Date.<init>(Date.java:255)
 at com.xcart.TodayQ.data(TodayQ.java:16)
 at com.xcart.Demo.main(Demo.java:5)

Comment: are you sure you're variable is of type "long"? because your stackTrace says it's entering the parse method which can be an indication that you're passing a string into the constructor

Comment: now i got the output is displayed always 1970-01-01
0...i can't understand dis.check the query and give me the count only.how is to do

Comment: Alexander Pogrebnyak's answer looks the most accurate to me.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming timestamp is time in millis, you can use java.util.Calendar to convert timestamp to date time as follows:

```
java.util.Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTimeInMillis(timestamp);
java.util.Date date = cal.getTime();
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the integer value you are seeing is the UNIX's number of seconds since the start of the Epoch ( which is 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z ) -> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_epoch

I don't know if the mysql JDBC driver will take care of converting this field for you.  If it does, the preferred way of getting its value is:

```
java.sql.Timestamp ts = result.getTimestamp( columnNumber );
```

Timestamp extends java.util.Date, so you can use it where regular java.util.Date is expected.

If, for whatever reason this does not produce desired result, then get the column value as `long` and adjust the value to milliseconds.  You are in luck here because Java's and UNIX's epochs start at the same time ( Java's is just more precise ).

```
long ts = result.getLong( columnNumber ) * 1000L;

java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date( ts );
```

Comment: This is probably the most accurate answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

to print the timestamp in yyyy-mm-dd:

```
Date date = new Date(timestamp);
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy-MM-dd");
System.out.println( dateFormat.format (date));
```

**UPDATE**

here is a HINT of how you can proceed:

```
public static int data() {
    int count = 0;
    Date now = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    System.out.println("TODAY IS:"+now.getTime()); //TODAY IS:1344007864862

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root", "");

        PreparedStatement statement1 = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM ORDERS WHERE STATUS = 'Q' AND DT= "+now.getTime());
        ResultSet rs1 = statement1.executeQuery();
        while (rs1 .next()) {
            count++; //A HIT IS FOUND
        }
    } catch (Exception exc) {
        System.out.println(exc.getMessage());
    }
    return count;
}
```

Obviously the now.getTime() returns the actual millisecond the date was captured in the **now** variable . The mathematics is all up to your implementation from now on.

Remember that the way to get a Calendar object at midnight (10/05/2012 00:00:00) is here [Java program to get the current date without timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2806360/java-program-to-get-the-current-date-without-timestamp)

Comment: it is also getting following exception:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
 at java.util.Date.parse(Date.java:598)
 at java.util.Date.<init>(Date.java:255)
 at com.xcart.TodayQ.data(TodayQ.java:16)
 at com.xcart.Demo.main(Demo.java:5)

Comment: are you sure the timestamps are valid? post the timestamp value thar generates the exception

Comment: now i got the output is displayed always 1970-01-01 0...i can't understand dis.check the query and give me the count only.how is to do

Comment: Alexander Pogrebnyak's answer looks the most accurate to me.

Answer (score 0):

The date column in the database should be a `TIMESTAMP` or `DATE` or `TIME`.

These are retrieved as `java.sql.Timestamp` or `java.sql.Date` or `java.sql.Time` respectively.

All of these classes extend `java.util.Date`.

So the data should already be in the format you are asking for.

So there is nothing to do.