# How to convert TimeStamp to Date in Java?

Tags: java, date, jdbc, timestamp

How do I convert 'timeStamp' to `date` after I get the count in Java?

My current code is as follows:

```
public class GetCurrentDateTime {

    public int data() {
        int count = 0;
        java.sql.Timestamp timeStamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
        java.sql.Date date = new java.sql.Date(timeStamp.getTime()); 
        System.out.println(date);
        //count++;

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pro", "root", "");

            PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("select * from orders where status='Q' AND date=CURDATE()");
            ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
            while (result.next()) {
                // Do something with the row returned.
                count++; //if the first col is a count.
            }
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            System.out.println(exc.getMessage());
        }

        return count;
    }
}
```

This is my database:
[image]

Here the output I got was 2012-08-07 0, but the equivalent query returns 3. Why do I get 0?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318719/how-to-convert-timestamp-string-to-java-util-date

Comment: Can you show us examples of what the table data looks like?

Comment: date(1344255451,1344255537,1344312502) and status have(Q,Q,Q)

Comment: Duplicate of this Question, [How to convert from java.sql.Timestamp to java.util.Date?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10621451/642706).

Comment: The title of this Question is [a red herring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring). The real problem is the improper use of a `PreparedStatement` with incorrect syntax. You cannot embed Java variables in the text of your SQL string. Instead, embed `?` in the SQL string, then call the `set` methods to pass values to the PreparedStatement. See the correct [Answer  by Sujay](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11839424/642706) and [Answer by tenorsax](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11839372/642706).

Comment: Tip: Never name a column in database with a keyword/reserved word like `date`. Append a trailing underscore to avoid such collisions. The SQL spec explicitly promises to never use a trailing underscore on any keyword or reserved word.

Comment: **Do not re-post your Question repeatedly!** This is a repeat of 4 days earlier: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11794648/642706

Comment: Do not store your date as a Unix timestamp. I can’t tell whether those timestamps fall on the date you mention, that is, verifying your code is more cumbersome than it had needed to be. Use the MySQL `date` datatype if you need the date only, a `timestamp` if you need the time.

Comment: Your question seems to assume that your unexpected result comes from incorrect conversion from an old-fashioned `java.sql.Timestamp` to an equally outdated `java.sql.Date`? This is not the case. Your `new java.sql.Date(timeStamp.getTime())` is a correctly working conversion.

Comment: For new readers to this question I strongly recommend you don’t use `java.sql.Timestamp` and `java.sql.Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `OffsetDateTime` for a timestamp and `LocalDate` for a date; both from are [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 217):

Just make a new `Date` object with the stamp's `getTime()` value as a parameter.

Here's an example (I use an example timestamp of the current time):

```
Timestamp stamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
Date date = new Date(stamp.getTime());
System.out.println(date);
```

Comment: @vs06 What makes you think it is deprecated? The latest java 7 and 8 docs both say otherwise (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime() and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime--)

Comment: This will produce an incorrect result if the Timestamp time zone and the JVM timezone are different.

Comment: How to get this formatted to 14.03.2014 for example?

Comment: I hate when ppl use libraries in their answers and expect everyone to know how to import them :/

Comment: Is the `Timestamp` class required? You can just do `Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());`

Answer (score 44):

```
// timestamp to Date
long timestamp = 5607059900000; //Example -> in ms
Date d = new Date(timestamp );

// Date to timestamp
long timestamp = d.getTime();

//If you want the current timestamp :
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
long timestamp = c.getTimeInMillis();
```

Comment: Why did you multiply it by 1000?

Comment: Beacause the initialization of the date is in milliseconds and the timestamp is in seconds !
Same think for all other convertion ! It's good ?

Answer (score 11):

Just:

```
Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(long);
Date date = new Date(timestamp.getTime());
```

Answer (score 9):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) )
    .atStartOfDay( ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) )
    .toEpochSecond()
```

…

```
LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) )
    .plusDays( 1 )
    .atStartOfDay( ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) )
    .toEpochSecond()
```

…

```
"SELECT * FROM orders WHERE placed >= ? AND placed < ? ; "
```

…

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( 1 , start )
myPreparedStatement.setObject( 2 , stop )
```

## java.time

You are using troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes.

Apparently you are storing a moment in your database in a column of some integer type. That is unfortunate. You should instead be using a column of a type such as the SQL-standard `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`. But, for this Answer, we will work with what we have.

If your records represent moments with a resolution of milliseconds, and you want all the records for an entire day, then we need a time range. We must have a start moment and a stop moment. Your query has only a single date-time criterion where it should have had a pair.

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

If no time zone is specified, the JVM implicitly applies its current default time zone. That default may change at any moment, so your results may vary. Better to specify your desired/expected time zone explicitly as an argument.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;  
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

If you want to use the JVM’s current default time zone, ask for it and pass as an argument. If omitted, the JVM’s current default is applied implicitly. Better to be explicit, as the default may be changed at any moment *during runtime* by any code in any thread of any app within the JVM.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;  // Get JVM’s current default time zone.
```

Or specify a date. You may set the month by a number, with sane numbering 1-12 for January-December.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 1986 , 2 , 23 ) ;  // Years use sane direct numbering (1986 means year 1986). Months use sane numbering, 1-12 for January-December.
```

Or, better, use the [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) enum objects pre-defined, one for each month of the year. Tip: Use these `Month` objects throughout your codebase rather than a mere integer number to make your code more self-documenting, ensure valid values, and provide [type-safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety).

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 1986 , Month.FEBRUARY , 23 ) ;
```

With a `LocalDate` in hand, we next need to transform that into a pair of moment, the start and stop of the day. Do not assume the day starts at 00:00:00 time-of-day. Because of anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST), the day may start at another time such as 01:00:00. So let java.time determine the first moment of the day. We pass a `ZoneId` argument to `LocalDate::atStartOfDay` to look up any such anomalies. The result is a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

```
ZonedDateTime zdtStart = ld.atStartOfDay( z ) ;
```

Generally the best approach to defining a span of time is the Half-Open approach where the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*. So a day starts with its first moment and runs up to, but not including, the first moment of the next day.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtStop = ld.plusDays( 1 ).atStartOfDay( z ) ;  // Determine the following date, and ask for the first moment of that day.
```

Our query for an entire day cannot make use of SQL command `BETWEEN`. That command is Fully-Closed (`[]`) (both beginning and ending are inclusive) where as we want Half-Open (`[)`). We use a pair of criteria `>=` and `<`.

Your column is poorly named. Avoid any of the thousand words reserved by various databases. Let’s use `placed` in this example.

Your code should have used `?` placeholders in which to specify our moments.

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE placed >= ? AND placed < ? ; " ;
```

But we have `ZonedDateTime` objects in hand, while your database apparently is storing integers as discussed above. If you *had* defined your column properly we could simply pass the `ZonedDateTime` objects with any JDBC driver supporting JDBC 4.2 or later.

But instead we need to get a count-from-epoch in whole seconds. I will assume your epoch reference date is the first moment of 1970 in UTC. Beware of possible data loss, as the `ZonedDateTime` class is capable of nanosecond resolution. Any fractional second will be truncated in the following lines.

```
long start = zdtStart().toEpochSecond() ;  // Transform to a count of whole seconds since 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z.
long stop = zdtStop().toEpochSecond() ;
```

Now we are ready to pass those integers to our SQL code defined above.

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement( sql );
ps.setObject( 1 , start ) ;
ps.setObject( 2 , stop ) ;
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

When you retrieve your integer values from the [`ResultSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html), you can transform into [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) objects (always in UTC), or into [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) objects (with an assigned time zone).

```
Instant instant = rs.getObject( … , Instant.class ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 8):

I have been looking for this since a long time, turns out that [Eposh converter](https://www.epochconverter.com/) does it easily:

```
long epoch = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss").parse("01/01/1970 01:00:00").getTime() / 1000;
```

Or the opposite:

```
String date = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(new java.util.Date (epoch*1000));
```

Answer (score 7):

try to use this java code :

```java
Timestamp stamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
Date date = new Date(stamp.getTime());
DateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
DateFormat f1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
String d = f.format(date);
String d1 = f1.format(date);
System.out.println(d);
System.out.println(d1);
```

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you're not leveraging the advantage of using a `PreparedStatement`. I would first suggest that you modify your `PreparedStatement` as follows:

```
PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("select * from orders where status=? AND date=?")
```

You can then use `statement.setXX(param_index, param_value)` to set the respective values. For conversion to `timestamp`, have a look at the following javadocs:

[PreparedStatement.setTimeStamp()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setTimestamp%28int,%20java.sql.Timestamp%29) 
[Timestamp](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

In Android its very Simple .Just use the Calender class to get currentTimeMillis.

```
Timestamp stamp = new Timestamp(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());
Date date = new Date(stamp.getTime());
Log.d("Current date Time is   "  +date.toString());
```

In Java just Use System.currentTimeMillis() to get current timestamp

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what you're trying to select in the query, but keep in mind that `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` without arguments returns the time now. You should probably provide a valid time as argument, or change the condition.

***EDIT:***

Here is an example of a time bound query based on the question:

```
PreparedStatement statement = con
        .prepareStatement("select * from orders where status='Q' AND date > ?");
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse("01/01/2000");
statement.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(date.getTime()));
```

***EDIT: timestamp column***

In case of timestamp use `java.sql.Timestamp` and [PreparedStatement.setTimestamp()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setTimestamp%28int,%20java.sql.Timestamp%29), ie:

```
PreparedStatement statement = con
        .prepareStatement("select * from orders where status='Q' AND date > ?");
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse("01/01/2000");
Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
statement.setTimestamp(1, timestamp);
```

Comment: now my condition is select * from xcart_orders where status='Q' AND date=CURDATE().now also displayed zero only

Comment: @krishnaveni what records are you trying to select?

Comment: date(11111111,123456767,122333344) and status=(Q,Q,Q)..all are saved in my database.now i wish to need check the query and get the count value and display on my console(ie)how many datas are matched after return the count value

Comment: @krishnaveni If you want the resultset to be bound by a certain date then use that date in the query, otherwise remove the date condition.

Comment: in my code is works successfully when date is in yyyy-mm-dd format saved in my database . But now my date is saved in a timestamp in this 1343469690 format. How is get the count value?how is i wrote a code here

Comment: @krishnaveni use `java.sql.Timestamp` for timestamp column, see my last edit.

Answer (score 3):

`new Date(timestamp.getTime())` should work, but the new fancy Java 8 way (which may be more elegant and more type safe, as well as help lead you to use the new time classes) is to call `Date.from(timestamp.toInstant())`.

(Do not rely on the fact that `Timestamp` itself is an instance of `Date`; see explanation in the comments of [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18080498/421049) .)

Answer (score 3):

```
    Timestamp tsp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
   java.util.Date dateformat = new java.util.Date(tsp.getTime());
```

Answer (score 3):

I feel obliged to respond since other answers seem to be time zone agnostic which a real world application cannot afford to be. To make timestamp-to-date conversion correct when the timestamp and the JVM are using different time zones you can use Joda Time's LocalDateTime (or LocalDateTime in Java8) like this:

```
Timestamp timestamp = resultSet.getTimestamp("time_column");
LocalDateTime localDateTime = new LocalDateTime(timestamp);
Date trueDate = localDateTime.toDate(DateTimeZone.UTC.toTimeZone());
```

The example below assumes that the timestamp is UTC (as is usually the case with databases). In case your timestamps are in different timezone, change the timezone parameter of the `toDate`statement.

Answer (score 1):

```java
import java.sql.Timestamp

new Timestamp(1234567890123L)
// java.sql.Timestamp = 2009-02-14 10:31:30.123

(new Timestamp(1234567890123L)).toLocalDateTime().toLocalDate().toString()
// 2009-02-14
```

What is a different result from one of the previous most voted answers:

```java
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
import java.time.ZoneId
import java.time.ZoneOffset

(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE).withZone(ZoneId.from(ZoneOffset.UTC)).format(new Timestamp(1234567890123L).toInstant())
// String = 2009-02-13
```

In my case, I was expecting the "2009-02-14" instead of the "2009-02-13". So the top result worked better for me.

Comment: First I recommend you don’t use `Timestamp`. Next, the different results come from different default time zones. Rather than writing code that happens to work with your default time zone I recommend specifying time zone explicitly.

Comment: That is the point: The solution using  DateTimeFormatter is considering my Timezone and fixing something that was not broken. About using or not Timestamp, that s not an option for me. Also, that is exactly the question title, right?

Comment: Sorry, You are correct. The preview from the Timestamp shows the timestamp to DateTime, considering my current time zone. That is why it does not match the UTC version. That particular timestamp 1234567890123L  in UTC should be ``Friday, 13 February 2009 23:31:30``, as we can see running ``new Timestamp(1234567890123L).toGMTString() ``. Therefore the correct answer should be "2009-02-13"

Answer (score 0):

```
String timestamp="";
Date temp=null;
try {
    temp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(getDateCurrentTimeZone(Long.parseLong(timestamp)));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
int dayMonth=temp.getDate();
int dayWeek=temp.getDay();
int hour=temp.getHours();
int minute=temp.getMinutes();
int month=temp.getMonth()+1;
int year=temp.getYear()+1900;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a pre-existing `java.util.Date date`:

```
Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(long);
date.setTime( l_timestamp.getTime() );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to get Date from Timestamp and Time-zone of particular area.

```
public String getDayOfTimestamp(long yourLinuxTimestamp, String timeZone) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTimeInMillis(yourLinuxTimestamp * 1000);
    cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZone));
    Date date = cal.getTime();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`Date updated =  timestamp.toDate();`

Comment: No. The outdated `java.sql.Timestamp` did not have a `toDate` method. And the question already shows a working conversion.

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score -3):

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date fecha = getDateInTimestamp();
```