# How can i convert timestamp value into date in java

Tags: java, mysql

I'm finding a way to store "083752" value (timestamp value in long data format) to Mysql database (type = DateTime). Thus, I need to convert that value to human readable date time. I use following code to do that.

```
long l = 083752;
Date date = new Date(l);
System.out.println(date.toString());
```

**Edit**
What i need to do is 83752 => 1/2/1970 4:45:52 AM

But it doesn't works. I followed this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11839246/how-to-convert-timestamp-to-date-in-java) also.

Comment: What date/time is 083752 intended to represent?

Comment: doesn;t work, elaborate

Comment: 083752 is timestamp. please can someone explain why downvote ?

Comment: You want to store a date in a database? Why do you need to format the date?

Comment: Is the integer literal meant to be octal?

Comment: Do you mean 08 h 37 min 52 sec, are you sure you want the same way?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, can you explain how it can do?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the time you are storing the time in millis, then

You may use java.util.Date class and then use SimpleDateFormat to format the Date.

```
Date date=new Date(millis);
```

for example:

```
long l = Long.parseLong("083752"); // mills
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(l);
System.out.println(formatter.format(calendar.getTime()));
```

This will return you the date

Comment: but long l give the error of out of range

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. Thanks for all who support me.

```
 long l = Long.parseLong("083752");
 String date1 = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(new java.util.Date(l * 1000));
 System.out.println(date1);
```

Comment: Yes, it works. i didn't mention parse long other than that my approach was correct