# How to convert created_time filed value to date from Instagram media object

Tags: java, instagram, instagram-api

I am wokring with instagram api. My requirement is how to convert or parse date from media object respose like `"created_time": "1279340983"?` any idea?

Comment: I am using java, I tried with examples but I have to convert to long type first and then pass that string to format method like  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd"); String date = sdf.format(created_time); but throwing an exception

Answer (score 2):

Once you have the response from the Instagram API, do this:

```
var t = response.created_time;
var date = new Date(t);
console.log(date);
```

If the time stamp is 1279340983, then:

```
var date = new Date(1279340983);
```

will convert the stamp to a date/time in your computer's local time zone.

Comment: Yes, it's javascript (sorry - I missed your tag).  Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11839246/how-to-convert-timestamp-to-date-in-java) helps with java.

Comment: Thanks for the update I have got the answer from [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35330889/convert-date-string-to-readable-date-format)

Answer (score 0):

The Instagram API responds with a "created_time" JSON object that is formatted as a Unix timestamp, AKA milliseconds since 00:00:00 1 Jan 1970.

Here is a great resource on how to convert Unix timestamps in various languages to human readable dates: https://www.epochconverter.com/programming/#javascript

Here is the Javascript:

```
 var myDate = new Date( response.created_time *1000);
 document.write(myDate.toGMTString()+"<br>"+myDate.toLocaleString());
```

and this code creates:

`Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT
 12/31/1969, 4:00:01 PM`