# Convert date string to readable date format

Tags: java

I am receiving the date as "1279340983" so I want to convert to readable format like 2010-07-17. I have tried using following code

```
String createdTime = "1279340983";
Date date1 = new Date(Long.parseLong(createdTime));
SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
System.out.println(sdf1.format(date1));
```

but it returns `1970-01-16`as output. when tried to online tool it is showing `Sat, 17 Jul 2010 04:29:43 GMT` any idea why this code not showing intended output ?

Comment: How this is possible to `2010-07-2010`? your format is `yyyy-MM-dd`.

Comment: sorry it's typo I have edited

Comment: Just to verify, the number that you have is milliseconds, right?

Comment: `new Date(1279340983000L)` is 2010-07-17.

Comment: timestamps in java use milliseconds, not seconds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your given time does not has time zone included so the Java will take local time zone,

```
    String createdTime = "1279340983";
    Date date1 = new Date(Long.parseLong(createdTime) * 1000); // right here
    System.out.println(date1.toString()); // this is what you are looking online
    SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss zzz"); // here you would have to customize the output format you are looking for
    System.out.println(sdf1.format(date1));
```

> output

```
Sat Jul 17 09:59:43 IST 2010 // this would be your online result 
2010-07-17 09:59:43 IST      // this is something you want to change ,
```

you might want to change the time zone should you like to have that

```
sdf1.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
```

> output
>   2010-07-17 04:29:43 GMT

Comment: This is exactly I am looking for. Things to be observed here is convert createdTime from seconds to milliseconds

Comment: @SrinivasDJ, yes you are right

Answer (score 0):

The online converter you're using is converting date from *seconds*. Java's `Date` constructor uses `milliseconds`, not seconds. You need to multiply your answer by 1000 to make it match.

```
    String createdTime = "1279340983";
    Date date1 = new Date(Long.parseLong(createdTime) * 1000); // right here
    SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    System.out.println(sdf1.format(date1));
```