# How to get Instagram posts by year?

Tags: android, flutter, instagram

I am new to Instagram Api. I need to know is there any endpoint or other way to get all the posts of a certain year Or most popular posts of a year? If there is then how can i do so using android or flutter?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `created_time` parameter from Response of request (for example: GET/users/self/media/recent) to identify date of creation.

For more information check Instagram API:
https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/

If you need to know how to convert `created_time` to date:
[How to convert created_time filed value to date from Instagram media object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35329944/how-to-convert-created-time-filed-value-to-date-from-instagram-media-object)

If you want to implement it in android or flutter. You must to search: "How to send get request in java/flutter".

For example, I google it for Flutter:
https://flutter.io/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks but i didn't ask for that actually. i asked for images of particular year.