# Get date part in cassandra and scala

Tags: scala, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector, nosql

How get date part in cassandra and scala? Somebody can help me please?

e.g  2014-11-22 13:23 I want extract 
     "yyyy"
     "MM"
     "DD"

e.g
     SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM OrderDate) 
        EXTRACT(MONTH FROM OrderDate) 
         EXTRACT(DAY FROM OrderDate)

expected result
2014
11
22

I want extract date part, i don't want convert date format. So, the [How to convert TimeStamp to Date in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11839246/how-to-convert-timestamp-to-date-in-java), not resolve my problem.

Comment: What object do you have as a Date? Is it a timestamp? java.sql.Date?

Comment: I have date in timestamp.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert TimeStamp to Date in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11839246/how-to-convert-timestamp-to-date-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

I hope you found the anwser, but you try to do two things:

1. In Cassandra: Create a function inside the kespace;

   cqlsh> use keyspace;

   cqlsh:keyspace> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Year(input DATE)
   RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT RETURNS TEXT
   LANGUAGE java AS 'return input.toString().substring(0,4);';
2. In Spark: You can use the spark function [Function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#year)

e.g

```
SELECT year(OrderDate), month(OrderDate), day(OrderDate) from ...
```