# How to convert PHP timestamp to display datetime format as string in Java (difference UTC)?

Tags: java, php, android

How to convert PHP timestamp to display datetime format as string in Java (difference UTC)?

```
<?php
echo date('d-m-Y h:i:sa',1495221086);
// Result: 19-05-2017 09:11:26pm

<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Phnom_Penh'); // UTC+07:00
echo date('d-m-Y h:i:sa',1495221086);
// Result: 20-05-2017 02:11:26am
```

Question: how to convert 1495221086 to 20-05-2017 02:11:26am in Java?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert TimeStamp to Date in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11839246/how-to-convert-timestamp-to-date-in-java)

Comment: No duplicated ..

Comment: difference timezone (UTC+7:00)

Comment: How to change UTC+0:00 to UTC+7:00 in Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using Java's standard (legacy) classes `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`, as follows:

```
Date date = new Date(1495221086*1000L);
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(
    "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ssa", Locale.UK /* for displaying "AM" correctly */);
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Phnom_Penh"));
System.out.println(df.format(date));
```

This prints out

```
20-05-2017 02:11:26AM
```

Comment: Oh. I didn't know about the *1000L. Thanks

Comment: I spent many times for searching this problem, now It work. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

I think this would do the trick:

```
Date date = new Date(1495221086 * 1000L);
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss aaa");
simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Phnom_Penh"));
String dateFormated = simpleDateFormat.format(date);
Log.i("MyInfo", "dateFormated: " + dateFormated);
```

Comment: For android TimeZones: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-date-time/java-util-timezone.html

Comment: The actual date is off here (millis vs seconds).

Comment: I/MyInfo: dateFormated: 18-01-1970 14:20:21 下午

Comment: Yes. You need to change the Timezone to "Asia/Phnom_Penh"