# How convert Timestamp to Date

Tags: java, date, timestamp

Other system send for us Timestamp in their time zone.If we run that in cloud in other system is +2 hours. Local is good because the server is the same time zone. How can I be sure that the time will always be right?

```
String TIME_STAMP_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss.SSSSSS";

DateTimeFormatter TIME_STAMP_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(TIME_STAMP_FORMAT, Locale.getDefault());

private static Timestamp parseTimestamp(String dateString) {
        try {
            return Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDateTime.parse(dateString, TIME_STAMP_FORMATTER));
        } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
            log.error("Not able to parse timestamp", e);
        }
        return null;
    }

Date afterParse =  parseTimestamp('2018-12-31-12.30.50.000200')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert TimeStamp to Date in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11839246/how-to-convert-timestamp-to-date-in-java)

Comment: `Date` is deprecated since Java 1.8 because of consistency and time zone issues. What is `Timestamp`? It's not one of Java's general-purpose classes.

Comment: Your problem is not conversion to date. Your problem is that your systems create a string where you have to guess the time zone. It's better to ensure the strings sent by the system are adjusted to UTC and in a standard format that indicates this. These will be very easy to convert. Local times should only be used when the actual instance is not important.

Comment: I have no influence on the string that comes in from the external system. I have to get around it somehow. I know the `Date` is deprecated but there are too many changes if I change the type. Which part suggests it's UTC?

Comment: It’s likely a kind of duplicate, but, @dodekja, not of that particular question.

Comment: I recommend you neither use nor want `Timestamp` nor `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated. And even more strongly as you are already using [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Instead for a timestamp use `Instant` from java.time.

Comment: To answer your question, if you are sure that the other system is always sending date-time at offfset +02:00, a correct conversion exists. If they may be using some time zone that uses summer time (DST) and/or other anomalies, there is no way to be sure to get the correct time.

Comment: I didn’t understand this part, sorry: *If we run that in cloud in other system is +2 hours. Local is good because the server is the same time zone.* Can you explain more clearly?

Comment: These are my suspicions. Because when I checked on test in AWS is +2. When I testing this test case local is ok. Test case is:
1. I send req to external server.
2. They response for me String with specific format.
3. I have to save this date in UTC in database.
4. I know the date is in CET timezone.

Comment: CET is not +02:00, it’s +01:00. And on December 31 no summer time (DST, CEST) is in effect. So still confused about your desired result.

Comment: @Deluxxx Post further details as edits to your Question rather than as Comments. The reader should not have to trawl through the Comments to understand the Question.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

> How can I be sure that the time will always be right?

- Include an indicator of [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) or [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) with your date-time input string.
- Use standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats when exchanging date-time values.
- Use only *java.time* classes in Java. Never use `Date`, `Timestamp`, `Calendar`, etc.
- Tip: Adjust values from other zones to UTC before sending (generally speaking).

If not possible, then here is a workaround. This assumes you know the time zone intended by the sender of this poor data.

```
LocalDateTime                           // Represent a date and time-of-day without the context of a time zone or offset-from-UTC. NOT a moment, NOT a point on the timeline. A meaningless value until you assign a zone/offset.
.parse(
    "2018-12-31-12.30.50.000200" ,      // Avoid such custom formats. Use only ISO 8601 when exchanging date-time values textually.
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss.SSSSSS" )  // Define formatting pattern to match youre input.
)                                       // Returns a `LocalDateTime` object.
.atZone(                                // Give meaning to the `LocalDateTime` object by applying a time zone.
    ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" )         // Always specify a time zone with `Continent/Region` name, never the 2-4 character pseudo-zones popularly seen in the media.
)                                       // Returns a `ZonedDateTime` object.
.toInstant()                            // Adjust from a time zone to UTC by extracting an `Instant` object. Same moment, same point on the timeline, different wall-clock time.
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/Z3h8nZ).

Best to avoid `java.util.Date` class. But if you must interoperate with old code not yet updated to *java.time*, you can convert. Call on the new methods added to the old classes such as `Date.from( Instant )`.

## Avoid legacy classes

Never use `java.sql.Timestamp` nor `java.util.Date`. All of the date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java are now legacy, per the adoption of JSR 310. Use only the modern *java.time* classes.

## Wrong data type

You are using the wrong data type. To track a moment, a specific point on the timeline, you must have a time zone or offset-from-UTC. The `LocalDateTime` class exactly the wrong class to use here. That class purposely lacks any concept of zone or offset. So it is the opposite of what you want.

To track a moment, use `Instant`, `OffsetDateTime`, or `ZonedDateTime`.

[image: Table of date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy.]

Where the *java.time* classes have methods with an optional time zone (`ZoneId`) or offset-from-UTC (`ZoneOffset`) argument, consider the argument required. **Always pass a zone/offset.** Then you never need worry about how the sysadmin is setting the JVM’s current default time zone at runtime.

```
ZonedDateTime.now(                    // Capture the current moment as seen through the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region (a time zone).
    ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" )
)
```

Or, use `Instant` which is always in UTC, by definition.

```
Instant.now()                         // Capture the current moment in UTC.
```

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `Continent/Region`, such as `America/Montreal`, `Africa/Casablanca`, or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

## ISO 8601

Your question is not clear, but it seems you are receiving an input string for a date-time in a custom format. I suggest you educate the people publishing that data about the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard. This standard defines practical formats for date-time values being exchanged between systems textually.

The *java.time* classes use the ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating strings.

## Workaround

If the data publisher is sending you values such as `2018-12-31-12.30.50.000200` in order to communicate a moment, they have failed. A date and time-of-day without a zone or offset is useless, like communicating an amount of money without indicating a currency.

Do you know for certain the time zone that was implicitly assumed by the sender of this faulty data input? If so, apply it, as a clumsy stop-gap measure for their poor practice.

First parse your input as a `LocalDateTime` given that it lacks any indicator of zone/offset.

```
String input = "2018-12-31-12.30.50.000200" ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss.SSSSSS" ) ;
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input , f ) ;
```

Apply a [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html) to get a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) object, thereby adjusting to view the moment through the wall-clock time used by the people of that particular region.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( ldt ) ;
```

Generally best to work with moments in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), unless you have a specific reason to use a time zone (such as presentation to user). So extract an [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html) from your `ZonedDateTime`.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;
```

The `Z` at the end of an ISO 8601 compliant string means UTC, and is pronounced “Zulu”.

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/Z3h8nZ).

> input: 2018-12-31-12.30.50.000200
>
> ldt: 2018-12-31T12:30:50.000200
>
> zdt: 2018-12-31T12:30:50.000200+09:00[Asia/Tokyo]
>
> instant: 2018-12-31T03:30:50.000200Z

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Just a small supplement to [Basil Bourque’s clever and very informative answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55504134/5772882).

> 4. I know the date is in CET timezone.

I am sorry, this is not enough. Central European Time (CET) is the common term for quite many European and African(!) time zones the details of which differ. The European ones are generally at offset +01:00 during standard time and at +02:00 during summer (known as Central European Summer Time or CEST). The African ones are at +01:00 all year. For past dates, just a few decades back, some zones used summer time (DST), others didn’t, some were at +00:00, +01:00 or +02:00, and further back in history many other offsets were used, generally not whole hours.

The future is even worse! It has been suggested that the European Union abandons summer time and leaves it to each member state whether they will use permanent standard time or permanent summer time, avoiding the time adjustments in spring and autumn. There is a power struggle going on about this, so we don’t know whether it will happen, nor what each member state chooses. So even if you could tell me the exact time zone of your string from the other system (for example, Europe/Sarajevo), no one knows yet whether `2019-11-01-00.30.50.000200` — less than 7 months from now — will be at offset +01:00 or +02:00.

Link: [European MPs vote to end summer time clock changes](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-47704345) on BBC News.