# Firebase timestamp doesn't retrieve timestamp in SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, timestamp

Been working on this `timestamp` for ages and using numerous posts from StackOverflow to help me through it. Finally got `timestamp` saving in Firebase along with all the other children for the pictures, but I can't get it to come upon the app in the `TextView`.

So in my `PostActivity.java` class I have used `Map` to save the `timestamp` to Firebase, and then in my `PostAdapter.java` class I have the `ViewHolders` so that it appears in the `RecyclerView` in my `HomeFragment`, but it's coming out as a `Long` value `41526276373`and not in `SimpleDateFormat` as it should.

Can someone help me?

Below you have my `PostActivity.java` class and `PostAdapter.java` class.

**PostActivity.java**

```
 DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts");

                        String postid = reference.push().getKey();

                        HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                        hashMap.put("postid", postid);
                        hashMap.put("postimage", myUrl);
                        hashMap.put("description", txt_description.getText().toString());
                        hashMap.put("text_event", txt_event.getText().toString());
                        hashMap.put("text_location", txt_location.getText().toString());
                        hashMap.put("text_date_time", txt_date_time.getText().toString());
                        hashMap.put("publisher", FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
                        hashMap.put("timestamp", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);

                        reference.child(postid).setValue(hashMap);

                        //Do I have to put here reference.updateChildren(hashmap)?

                        progressDialog.dismiss();

                        startActivity(new Intent(PostActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                        finish();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, "Unsuccessful. Try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, "" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No Image Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public static String getTimeDate(long timestamp) {
        try {
            DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance();
            Date netDate = (new Date(timestamp));
            return dateFormat.format(netDate);
        } catch (Exception e){
            return "timestamp";
        }
    }
```

**PostAdapter.java**

```
 @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.post_item, parent, false);
        return new PostAdapter.ViewHolder(view);

    }
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    final Post post = mPost.get(position);

    Glide.with(mContext).load(post.getPostimage())
            .apply(new RequestOptions().placeholder(R.drawable.placeholderimg))
            .into(holder.post_image);

    if ("".equals(post.getTimestamp())) {
        holder.timestamp.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        if (post.getPostid() != null) {
            holder.timestamp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.timestamp.setText(post.getTimestamp().toString());
        }
    }
```

**PostAdapter.java Updated**

```
if ("".equals(post.getTimestamp())) {
            holder.timestamp.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            if (post.getPostid() != null) {
                holder.timestamp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
               ***holder.timestamp.setText(post.getTimeDate());***
            }
        }

***getTimeDate(post.getPostid(), holder.timestamp);***

public String getTimeDate(long timestamp) {
        try {
            DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance();
            Date netDate = (new Date(this.timestamp));
            return dateFormat.format(netDate);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After writing the below answer, I suddenly noticed you don't seem to be calling your `getTimeDate` helper method from anywhere in the view holder, which would explain why the timestamp shows up as a number.

---

When you save a `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` in Firebase Realtime Database, it stores a value that counts the number of milliseconds that have passed since the epoch. So this is indeed a numerical (and rather large) value.

To show it as a date, pass it into `new Date(...)`:

```
holder.timestamp.setText(new Date(post.getTimestamp()));
```

In many cases I've seen developers add a convenience method to their POJO Java class, such as the `Post` class in your case. Something like:

```
class Post .... {
    ...

    public String getTimeDate(long timestamp) {
        try {
            DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance();
            Date netDate = (new Date(this.timestamp));
            return dateFormat.format(netDate);
        } catch (Exception e){
            return new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

}
```

And then use that in your view holder as:

```
holder.timestamp.setText(post.getTimeDate());
```

Also see:

- [How to convert TimeStamp to Date in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11839246/how-to-convert-timestamp-to-date-in-java)

Comment: Hey man, thanks for the explanation. Has brought me  a lot closer to my end goal. Could you please explain the last part of the ```getTimeDate``` method that you wrote above? I don't understand the ```return new RuntimeException(e);``` part... Also, it comes back underlined in red the code. Shouldn't it be a ```String```? If you could explain it so I can understand it better

Comment: Darn.. I haven't done date manipulation in Java in a while, so should've known better. I just noticed that your code swallowed the exception, and you'll probably want to instead rethrow it. Feel free to surface it in another way, such as logging it.

Comment: The lines with *** are still wrong and I don't know why. I changed the method to throw the exception I think. I updated the text with ***PostAdapter.java Updated***

Comment: If you're having trouble improving the error handling, feel free to leave what you had. It was just a minor (intended) improvement and not related to your actual problem.

Comment: The ```holder.timestamp.setText(new Date(post.getTimestamp()));``` was spot on, but the second one is the better option for me considering I want to change the date format, this is why I am trying to figure out why the changed lines of code are being underlined in red