# How to convert timestamp date to java.util date(yyyy-mm-dd) in java

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am getting date from Oracle is in `Timestamp` but I need to convert it in to this format `2020-02-17` (yyyy-mm-dd) format, but currently in postman I am receiving date as `"2020-02-17T09:40:37.850+0000"` in this format.
Any help on this would be really appreciated

Comment: Just extract the first 10 characters of the inputted date, and pass it to another date object. You could also use the SimpleDateFormat, but that's using the longest possible method.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily convert a `java.sql.Timestamp` to a `java.time.LocalDate` and get a date `String` by formatting the `LocalDate` like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // just a timestamp stub that takes "now"
    java.sql.Timestamp ts = java.sql.Timestamp.from(Instant.now());
    // convert it to a modern date object
    LocalDate justDate = ts.toLocalDateTime().toLocalDate();
    // print it using a suitable formatter
    System.out.println(justDate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE));
}
```

The output (today) is

```
2020-02-17
```

**You just need Java 8 or higher for this or import a [backport library](https://github.com/ThreeTen/threetenbp).**

**EDIT**

If you don't need a `String` but a `java.util.Date`, do it with `Instant` only, like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // just a timestamp stub that takes "now"
    Instant now = Instant.now();
    Timestamp ts = Timestamp.from(now);
    // create an Instant from the Timestamp
    Instant timestampInstant = ts.toInstant();
    // and then create a Date out from that Instant
    java.util.Date creationDate = java.util.Date.from(now);

    // do something with the Date here...
}
```

**But please consider using `java.time` wherever possible, which might be in your domain class...**

Comment: Thanks for quick revert.But my domain class is having Date field 'creationDate',,so how can i set that string back to date. Currently justDate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE) its  a string

Answer (score 1):

```
 private String  getZonedDateTime(String startTime){
  // input -> startTime: 2020-02-17T09:40:37.850+0000
  // output -> 2020-02-17
  return ZonedDateTime.parse(startTime, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX"))
                .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"));
 }
```

Just pass the Date String which you have and get it in what format you want.

Comment: Thanks,,,but all this is string how can i get the same in Date variable.

Comment: You cannot have a `Date` object with a format. See for example [want current date and time in “dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SS” format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8745297/want-current-date-and-time-in-dd-mm-yyyy-hhmmss-ss-format). @TaherAli

Answer (score 0):

That question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11839246/how-to-convert-timestamp-to-date-in-java/11839276#11839276)

And what you want exactly, to display the date with that format or save with that format.

If you want display the date with (yyyy-mm-dd)

```
String dateFormated = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(myTimestamp);
System.out.println(dateFormated);
```

If you want save the date with that format you can try to do this:

```
try {
     SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd);
     String dateFormated = dateFormat.format(myTimestamp);
     Date parsedDate = dateFormat.parse(dateFormated);
     Timestamp timestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(parsedDate.getTime());
} catch(Exception e) { 

}
```

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.